# Hook/Filter before and after comments

Tags: comments

I'm writing a plugin that needs to display a custom link immediately near the comments.  I have the option in the plugin admin to display before or after.  I'm familiar with the comments_array, but that doesn't allow me to just add a string of html just before the comments or just after the comments but before the comment form.

```
the_content
-- ?? custom link before ?? --
comments_array
-- ?? custom link after ?? --
comment_form
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`do_action( 'comment_form_before' );` is called on line 1553 of /wp-includes/comment-template.php, right before the output of the comment form, that should handle that one for you. I'll update this if I can find the hook before the comments.

## edit

It seems like you might be able to modify Walker_Comment (found in the same file as above) to output the first link with __construct or something, but I can't give you precise implementation at the moment (for lack of time).

Comment: Yes, I was able to use the do_action to at least place the html before the form, after the comments_array.

Answer (score 8):

I think, this is the post, that you search; all hooks on comments form visualized: http://wpengineer.com/2205/comment-form-hooks-visualized/

alternativ all hooks:

- comment_form_before
- comment_form_top
- comment_form_before_fields
- comment_form_after_fields
- comment_form
- comment_form_after

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice way to visualize those hooks but they're all about the comment_form and I needed to place html before/after the comments_array.